# Is it needed to call Bitmap.recycle() after used (in Android)?

Tags: android, bitmap, recycle

According to Android Reference Document of `Bitmap.recycle()`:

> Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the
>   reference to the pixel data. This will not free the pixel data
>   synchronously; it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there
>   are no other references. The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it
>   will throw an exception if getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and
>   will draw nothing. This operation cannot be reversed, so it should
>   only be called if you are sure there are no further uses for the
>   bitmap. **This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called,
>   since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no
>   more references to this bitmap.**

But, many books I read suggest to free memory by calling Bitmap.recycle() once make sure no longer need it.

It make me confused: Is it needed to call `Bitmap.recycle()` after used?

Comment: The GC will free up the Bitmap when it's not used, but calling the `recycle()` will help the GC to check if that part of the memory is free. Calling `recycle()` when loading and unloading Bitmaps (like in a list or gallery) may be a good practice

Answer (score 21):

It depends.

If you run your app on Android 3.0 and above, it's not needed as the GC will take care of it perfectly.

However, if you run your app on older versions, since bitmaps don't get monitored well by the GC (it thinks they are the size of a reference), you could get OOM, as shown on Google IO lecture [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk).

In any case, it's still recommended to call recycle as soon as you are sure you don't need the bitmap anymore. It's good even for new android versions, since it lowers the work needed for automatic memory management...

In fact, I remember I've asked a similar question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954435/what-does-calling-bitmap-recycle-on-api-11-do).

Also, if you need extra control of bitmaps using JNI, check out [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom).

So, in short, the answer is that it's not needed anymore, but still recommended.

---

EDIT: Ever since Android 8.0, Bitmaps are stored in native memory, so it's harder to reach OOM. In fact, it's technically impossible, as you will get into other issues instead. More information about this can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48091403/878126).

Comment: so even if a methods finish, and the BMP file loos reference, 1.it won't free up fully on android, or 2. it will collect it's reference step by step such a way make it slow to recover? like Bitmap->PixelArrayData->Pixel it first Remove the bitmap which has no reference to it, then the pixelArrayData, and in third launch the pixel it selves

Comment: As long as anything still holds a reference to it and can use it, it won't be recycled, just like any other Java object. BTW, I've decided to add a note in my answer about Android 8.0.

Comment: well if it's not defined in long running process as global, like involved class, or and long running like while true loop, it shouldn't be matter, at some point gc should start work, and gather it all, or part of it....

long ago, when i start writing one of my first C# application, i noticed that when i generate Bitmap frame by frame, it take some part of memory over time, then OS clear some of it not all (windows) then again, until it full the ram, but using GC.Collect if i'm not wrong, after each frame or after a period it would remove whole unnecessaries

Comment: I think you had a bug on C#, or you just didn't really have a reference to those bitmaps anymore. I don't think it can ditch bitmaps automatically without a reason. Again, if there are no references to the object, the object can be freed. It can be as soon as it's not available, and it can be some time later.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, we run a heavy Bitmap compression in production code, and without calling `recycle()` we run into many OOM Exceptions in old `Lollypop` devices, and after adding it to the code, the number of OOM reduced significantly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary, but is highly recommended! It will speed up the memory freeing process and will save you of torture with Out Of Memory exception.

I would say its mandatory if you are going to do any serious an memory extensive work with Bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Prior Android 3.0 Bitmaps allocs native memory to store it's pixels, and the recycle() calls delete in that region.

Even with that the GC ins't guaranteed to free up that memory if there's still any references for it.

But this call looks like that helps GC to work better, I developed an app that does extensive usage of memory and running in newer devices calling that or not the app run nearly the same (for older it really improves some performance).