# When should I recycle a bitmap in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

Should I recycle a bitmap after assigning it to an ImageView? I always here talks of the importance of recycling bitmaps, but I am never quite sure when. So in my present case I get a bitmap from SDCard and then pass it to my imageView as

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

should I immediately call `bmp.recycle()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452192/is-it-needed-to-call-bitmap-recycle-after-used-in-android look at this question it may solve your confusion

Comment: no you should not do that. better `recycle bitmap` `onBackpressed()`